# Upgrading library projects to Angular 12?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-package-format

I'm trying to run this on library projects / projects that have a workspace:

```
ng update @angular/core @angular/cli @angular/material
```

It worked on one project, however for the rest I always get:

```
Cannot locate bin for temporary package: @angular/cli
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue after upgrading to ng 12.
We use nrwl/nx which makes everything even more tricky...

## Workaround

- install angular cli globally:
  `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`
- now get the path of this installation, e.g. in a new git-bash terminal (outside of my projects):
  `which ng`

  - will print e.g. `/c/Program Files/nodejs/ng`
    this should be the latest version that we have just installed
  - execute `"/c/Program Files/nodejs/ng" --version`  to make sure that you have the newest version (`12.0.3` in my case
- now I can run my updates: e.g. `"/c/Program Files/nodejs/ng" update  @angular/flex-layout @angular/cdk @angular/material`

### Notes

- maybe this [fix](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/6e34d1bf897dcbf76d8edd40a3d70e4d3f190312) will help - should arrive in ng 12.1
- I think this is a related bug-report: [angular-cli#20843](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20843)

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file then run the following command:

```
npm install
```

Or

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli

npm install -g @angular/cli
```